# Finding $[T]_E$ for a basis that is composed of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The linear transformation from $M_2 \rightarrow M_2 $ (Matrices that are 2x2)

$T\left[\begin{pmatrix}
        a & b \\
        0 & d \\
        \end{pmatrix}\right]=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 \\
        0 & 3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        0 & d \\
        \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 \\
        0 & 3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

Where E = 
$\left(    
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
,
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
,
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\right) $

Question:What is $[T]_E$ ?

So I've done some work and found that the vectors that result from plugging in components of E inside T are:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 3 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
,\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 6 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix} $$

How exactly do I combine these into $[T]_E $?

Do I have to represent the following matrices as a linear combination of E?

i.e. $ \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}=\alpha b_1 +\beta b_2 + \gamma b_3  $ in which I get $ \begin{bmatrix}
        1  \\
        2 \\
        0\\
        \end{bmatrix} $ ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write $T(E_1), T(E_2), T(E_3)$ as a linear combination of $E_1, E_2, E_3$, where $E_1, E_2, E_3$ are the matrices that consist a basis, i.e.
$$T(E_1) =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = 1\cdot E_1 + 2\cdot E_2 + 0\cdot E_3.$$

You can do the same for $T(E_2), T(E_3)$.

In order to create the transformation matrix with respect to the basis $E$, just put the coefficients as columns. For example the first column of the transformation matrix will be:
$$[T]_E = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & * & * \\ 2 & * & * \\ 0 & * & *\end{bmatrix}.$$

P.S. Notice that $T(E_3) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 6 \\ 0 & 9\end{bmatrix}.$